# Is S = span(S) true?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let S be a vector space and span($S$) a span of $S$. $S$ always has a $0$ vector so span($S$) also has $0$. And S is closure under addition and multiplication. Span($S$)'s components consist of a linear combination which is same as prior closure properties. So I think they have the same meaning but I intuitively guess my thought may be wrong at the same time. Is $S$ really equal to span($S$)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if $S$ is a vector space then $\text{span}(S) = S$. Your argument shows $\text{span}(S) \subseteq S$ and $S \subseteq \text{span}(S)$ is trivial by definition so we have equality.